# Как инициализировать UIView с xib-файлом?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

В проекте не используется `storyboard`, только `xib`-ы. Чтобы не наращивать код в контроллере инициализацией и настройкой `subview`, вынес основной View c `xib`-ом в отдельный класс `MyView`.

Как правильно инициализировать `self.myView` ?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self.view addSubview:self.myView];
    [self.myView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.myView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.myView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.myView.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor].active = YES;
}
```

И как переопределить метод `init` у класса `MyView`  (у класса есть `xib`), чтобы при инициализации сразу выполнить все необходимые настройки `subview` ?

```
@interface MyView ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *rightButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

...

@end

@implementation MyView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _rightButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [_rightButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rightButtonImage-normal"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_rightButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rightButtonImage-selected"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        ...

        _textField.rightView = _rightButton;
        _textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

        ...

    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создай свой инициализатор как метод класса (можно передавать любые параметры извне):

```
+ (instancetype)initWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    MyView *myView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    myView.backgroundColor = color;
    return myView;
}
```

В дальнейшем очень просто создаешь экземпляры:

```
[self.view addSubview:[MyView initWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]]];
```